# Test whether expected shortfalls of two portfolios are equal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, quantiles, finance, kurtosis

I have about 2000 daily observations of historical share prices for a handful of companies. I use a rolling window of 1000 observations to model their joint distribution. From each of the windows, I predict the joint distribution of the share prices one day ahead. Based on the prediction, I optimize a portfolio targeting a certain combination of risk and reward. (By *optimize a portfolio* I mean I find a set of nonnegative weights that sum up to 1. I use numerical optimization for that.) I collect the realized returns on the portfolio over 1000 windows. I also collect the realized returns on an equally-weighted (EW) portfolio over the same period.

I would now like to assess whether the optimally-weighted (OW) portfolio is doing any better than the EW one for a specific measure of risk, namely, the 2.5% [expected shortfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall#:%7E:text=Expected%20shortfall%20(ES)%20is%20a,of%20cases.)<sup>1</sup>. I can do a naïve comparison by looking at the mean of the 25 lowest returns from each portfolio. I find that the mean of the OW portfolio is higher than the mean of the EW portfolio, just as one would expect. However, I am not sure whether the difference is large enough to be statistically significant. **How can I test a null hypothesis that both ways of constructing portfolios from the given set of shares yield the same expected shortfall (against an alternative that the OW way is better)?**

I know how I would test a hypothesis that the expected return on one asset is equal to the expected return on another asset. I would assume the returns are i.i.d. and do a $t$-test. Or I would assume the difference in returns follows an ARMA-GARCH process and look at the significance of the intercept in that model. However, I am afraid the problem above is more complicated. I see the following challenges: (1) we are dealing with the tail of the distribution rather than the mean; (2) the weights of the OW portfolio are not fixed but have been estimated; (3) the weights have been estimated from rolling windows that are overlapping. I am rather lost.

If the problem is too hard as is, I would appreciate some insight on its special cases, e.g. ignoring the point (3). For the most basic version of the problem, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548988).

<sup>1</sup> $q$% expected shortfall is (the negative of) the expected value of the observations belonging to the left tail that is cut off at the $q$% quantile level. Synonyms of expected shortfall are conditional value at risk (CVaR), average value at risk (AVaR), expected tail loss (ETL), and superquantile.

Comment: Maybe quantile regression? Bootstrapping?

Comment: @user2974951, maybe. Quantile regression would be more natural for value at risk (VaR), not sure how to use it for expected shortfall (ES). Bootstrap is nontrivial to do for statistics involving the tails of the distribution. Not being an expert in it, I wonder how I could proceed.